# C error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Tags: c, cs50

I tried to create a struct that would incude a dynamic array:

```
typedef struct
{
    int idNode;
    int* n; //pointer to the int nodes in the dynamically created array of nodes
    n = calloc(MAX, sizeof(int)); //dynamic array to store the loser member of the pair 
    int counter = 0;
}
node;
```

But I get
**error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier**

Comment: You can't have statements or initialization inside structures. As a possible solution you could create a function to create and initialize the structure.

Comment: Please don't guess the C syntax. Programming doesn't work like that, you can't write code by trial & error. You must actually know how to write a `typedef struct` before attempting to declare one. Rather than asking the Internet about utterly fundamental stuff, please consult your C programming book.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value to `n` in the struct declaration. You need to provide a function (something like a constructor ;-) that initializes the structure and assigns a value to its members, including `n`:

```
void init_node(node* n)
{
    n->idNode = ...;
    n->n = calloc(MAX, sizeof(int));
    n->counter = 0;
}
```

Note: you still need to handle errors (e.g. `calloc` may fail) in the function and propagate errors to its caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have statements or initialize an variable inside a structures.

For fix your problem

```c
typedef struct Node {
    int idNode;
    int* n; //pointer to the int nodes in the dynamically created array of nodes
    int counter;
} node;

int main(void)
{
   node data = null;
   node.n = calloc(sizeof(int), MAX);
   node.idNode = 0;
   node.counter = 0;
   return (0)
}
```

Now you have initialize your struct

Comment: `main()` should return `int`

Comment: You think is a good idea to tell this person the solution or how to do it for himself?

Comment: @M.M the main function doesn't return anything necessary, in my code the main function returns ```void```, so I can write ```void main```.

Comment: @Cortana, you can check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c
Main function must return anything, even if it's not used anywhere. Only in microcontrollers can return nothing, but this is a exception, not the norm

Comment: Ok I didn't know thank you for the info. I corrected my answer. @JoséManuelRamos

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos: Freestanding implementations are normal, and they could be more common than the hosted environments you think of the “norm” since there may be multiple embedded systems in your television, car, appliances, and other devices, outnumbering  those in your personal computers. Do not think of things you personally experience as the “norm” and things other people work with as abnormal or exceptions. Plenty of engineers work with freestanding C implementations.

Answer (score 0):

### Starting point

> I tried to create a struct that would incude a dynamic array

The problem I see in your initial snippet is you mix definition, declaration and use.
From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration:

> Declaration of a variable is for informing to the compiler the following information: name of the variable, type of value it holds and the initial value if any it takes. i.e., declaration gives details about the properties of a variable. Whereas, Definition of a variable says where the variable gets stored.

---

## Steps to get a basic knowledge of how to do it.

1. Firstly, you must know how to create a struct.
2. The next step is how to typedef it.
3. The next step is how dynamic arrays are declarated, defined, created, stored, modified or destroyed (the life cycle). Pay attention to erros may occur during the execution. The happy path of create *things* in C is not the only one, there are plenty of errors out there!
4. The next step is how to insert them into a typedef'd struct.
5. And the last step is use that typedef struct with a dynamic array inside it. Even you can create multiple dynamic arrays in the struct!

Note: Steps, 1, 2 and 4 may be ordered in other ways depend on the programmer

There is no shortcuts, no trial and error and, of course, you must create test programs to ensure the stuff you want and the stuff you program are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = calloc(MAX, sizeof(int)); 
int counter = 0;
```

You cannot use statements to execute inside of the declaration of a structure. You need to initialize `n` and `counter` inside of a function after an object of `node` has been defined.

E.g.:

```
typedef struct
{
    int idNode;
    int* n; 
    int counter;
}
node;

int main (void) 
{
    node a;
    a.n = calloc(MAX, sizeof(int));
    a.counter = 0;  
}
```